# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'

Tags: react-native-vector-icons

I'm facing the following error when trying to run

```
react-native run android
```

The console acuses:

> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vector-icons'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-vector-icons:classpath'.
>
> > Could not find any matches for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+ as no versions of com.android.tools.build:gradle are available.
>
> Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
>
> Required by:
>            project :react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Same problem here. Seems like both links are down. Needs to report that to jcenter/bintray.

Comment: Check out my answer here!

Comment: If anyone is experiencing this issue currently (May/2022). Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70747328/7133482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the version of react-native-vector-icons did the trick

I actually found the answer in this post: [react native vector icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712552/react-native-vector-icons)

Made it work by making a change in the package.json file.

Changed the line:

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
```

To:

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
```

Comment: The way how you solve it is to update react-native to a higher version which does not use AGP 2.2.3. If you want to stick to the older version of react-native 5.0.0, you can use the workaround I provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734791/8034839

Answer (score 0):

Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53734791/8034839

Try to add this to your `build.gradle` file.

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try updating react-native-vector-icons.
2. If you don't want to update change classpath version to 2.2.3 instead of 2.3.+